# design of table with checked column or column with reference to primary key which is updatable

Tags: triggers, db2, foreign-keys, primary-key, create-table

I faced a problem when creating/designing tables in DB2.

I have two tables, table  `users` and table `countries` created as shown bellow

```
create table users
  (
  firstname         varchar(20)       not null,
  lastname          varchar(20)       not null,
  gender            char(1)           not null check (gender in ('M','F')),
  birthdate         date              not null,
  country           char(3)           not null,
  )

create table testing.countries
  (
  name      varchar(60)     not null,
  code2     char(2)         not null,
  code3     char(3)         not null
  )
```

I want to have in a column `country` in table `users` a 3-char code of a country of origin and during insertion of data to be checked if it is valid (or better to say if it exists) from the list of countries which are stored in table `countries`.

Because DB2 doesn't support a subquery/subselect in a check option (which would be the best for me) then it looks like a candidate for a foreign key on column `country` in `users` referencing to a primary key on column `code3` in `countries`. But in case there will be update of 3-char code of any country, it will be impossible to update it in simple way.
I know that the update of this will not be so often and can be done manually by first inserting new data to `countries`, then updating values in `users` and then deleting the old values in `countries` but unfortunately there will be more similar tables where data will have to be checked during insertion against another table and data in referenced table will be updated quite often and then the manual update is uncomfortable. And of course I want the data in `users` to be updated in case the update in `countries` will be done.

What I want to ask is how to solve this. I thought about some `before` or `instead of` trigger but BEFORE cannot be used to change data in other tables and INSTEAD OF is expecting UNTYPED VIEW not the TABLE

```
SQL0159N  The statement references an object that identifies an unexpected
object type. Object: "COUNTRIES". Object type: "TABLE". Expected object type:
"UNTYPED VIEW".  LINE NUMBER=2.  SQLSTATE=42809`
```

Can you please advise me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It *sounds* like you want a foreign key constraint, not a trigger.

Comment: yes, foreign key is one of the option, but how to make the column `code3` in a table `countries` updatable when it will be referenced?

Comment: Do you have control of the process that updates the data?  Is enforcing integrity there rather than by database constraints a possibility?

Comment: @dan1111: what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

try Something like this:

```
      create table testing.users
        (
        firstname         varchar(20)       not null,
        lastname          varchar(20)       not null,
        gender            char(1)           not null check (gender in ('M','F')),
        birthdate         date              not null,
        country           char(3)           not null
        )

      create table testing.countries
        (
        name      varchar(60)     not null,
        code2     char(2)         not null,
        code3     char(3)         not null
        )

      ALTER TABLE testing.users ADD CONSTRAINT testing.PK_Users PRIMARY KEY
        (firstname, lastname);

      ALTER TABLE testing.countries ADD CONSTRAINT testing.PK_Countries PRIMARY KEY
        (code3);

      ALTER TABLE testing.users ADD CONSTRAINT testing.FK_Users_Countries FOREIGN KEY
        (country)
        REFERENCES testing.users
        (code3)
        ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Comment: two questions:
1) why to create a PK on `users` table? not needed for solving this problem, or not?
2) on table `countries`, really create a PK on column `name`? The column in `users` is designed as char(3) to match the `code3` column in `countries` not the `name` column, the same is for referencing the FK

Comment: 1) not necessery, but a table must have primary key, its better 2) yes if you want do a foreign key 3) i modify my code for pk is code3 in contries table

Comment: the PK on table `users` is really not needed, at least in this case ... 
after the update of PK in `countries` it starts to make sense for me ... but still it is not what I want and what I asked for - you mentioned `ON DELETE CASCADE` but this I do not want, when I will (try to) delete an entry from `countries` which will be referenced then for sure I do not want to be entry from users deleted as well - in fact I want to stop so `ON DELETE RESTRICT` or `ON DELETE NO ACTION` has to be used instead. But I still do not know how to make the table `countries` updatable when `code3` is referenced